# Kotlin autowired in spring

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I'm pretty new to kotlin but done some extensive java before...

I tried to use kotlin and java in the same project but it looked very ugly and I didn't like that my classes were separated into two places. So now my project is 100% kotlin and there are problems...

I keep getting this error message:

```
lateinit property serviceX has not been initialized
```

I understand it means that service is not initialized yet, but how do i do initialized it then?

with java and spring, I did @Autowired or injected services in the constructor and was done.

what I need is for my REST to be able to use serviceX

```
@Component
@Path("/super")
open class SuperRest : BaseRest() {

@PUT
@Path("/test")
fun putTest(
        @Context securityContext: SecurityContext,
        @NotNull selected: String
) {
    val user = serviceX(securityContext)
   }

}
```

and in BaseRest I have tried to autowire serviceX
first, it was:

```
    @Autowired
    protected lateinit var serviceX: ServiceX
```

then it was just

```
    @Autowired
    lateint var serviceX: ServiceX
```

then I tried other solutions I found in SO

```
open class BaseRest @Autowired constructor(
    private val serviceX: ServiceX
) { ... }
```

Why is this?
I can still use other @autowired services in my rest just fine.
Just when I try to use them from BaseRest extension i will get

```
lateinit property serviceX has not been initialized
```

even without any lateinit property, i still somehow get this error..

```
private var serviceX: ServiceX = ServiceX()
```

it is still somehow not initialized, please help

Comment: Can you show the place of the usage of `serviceX`? You are probably accessing it before it is injected. Thanks

Comment: Probably because you aren't using Spring but Jersey to manage your rest endpoint and haven't properly setup the Jersey/Spring integration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand the

> Just when I try to use them from BaseRest extension i will get

part, but here is the code I came across and it's working fine as expected.

```
open class BaseRest {
  @Autowired
  protected lateinit var serviceX: ServiceX

  fun baseFun() {
      serviceX.serviceFun(SecurityContextImpl())
  }
}

@Component
open class SuperRest : BaseRest() {

  fun putTest(
    securityContext: SecurityContext,
    @NotNull selected: String
  ) {
    baseFun()
    val user = serviceX.serviceFun(securityContext)
  }
}
```

Bonus question : Why do you use `@PUT and @Path("/test")` annotations and not `@PutMapping("/test")` ?

Comment: sorry, cant get it to work, not even with this.. still not initialaized

Comment: Okay, so you'll need to provide more context. For example, your pom.xml Spring dependencies, and more about this "Just when I try to use them from BaseRest extension".
Also, as @m-deinum mentionned, do you really use Spring to manage your REST enpoint, or something else ? those `@PUT and @Path` seems suspicious.